Crypto trading/exchange platform charging me a annual tax
I'm still new to crypto but I'm trading with this site called trust-bit.net, I wanted to withdraw 100K to my Trust Wallet and eventually to my bank account.  They told me that they have to collect a annual tax between 0.5-1% and that before I can received the amount requested, that I have to pay $11,804 base on my balance with them.  I say okay, go ahead and deducted that amount from the amount that I requested, they say that they cannot do that and that I have to pay it with my own money.  I know that there are fees and taxes but this sounds like a scam or fraud to trick me to give them money.  Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Also see How to tell if a cryptocurrency exchange or trading platform is trustworthy?
